# Extend wireless via Ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking

To address a weak WiFi signal to my home office, I've run an Ethernet cable from my WiFi router to my home office.  The cable can't reach my office desk so I can't connect it to my laptop.

I would like to connect the Ethernet cable to a WiFi device and extend the existing WiFi network or create a new WiFi network.   I was considering buying another WiFi router to do this but that seems like overkill.    I've searched for Ethernet WiFi bridges but those products appear to be a few years old.  Of the WiFi extenders I've looked at, many provide an Ethernet port but none so far have been able to use Ethernet a source for the signal.  Any suggestions on what I should use?

Comment: The cheapest answer is to extend the Ethernet cable. It seems like overkill to use a WiFi network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ll need a WiFi Access Point. However, for SOHO use, buying a regular WiFi Router is often a lot less expensive.

On this WiFi router, you’d have to:

1. Change its IP address so it’s in your existing subnet yet doesn’t conflict with anything
2. Disable DHCP
3. Set the WiFi name and security to the same settings as your existing router
4. Connect it to your existing network using a LAN(!) port on the device – the WAN port will remain unused

This will effectively extend your WiFi network with another cell, allowing devices to roam between the two.

A WiFi Extender is for locations were you cannot install a wired connection to upstream. It connects to your existing router wirelessly and creates another network cell. It offers inferior performance compared to a wired connection but is easier to set up.

A WiFi Bridge works much like a WiFi Extender except it doesn’t service wireless devices but offers a way to bring non-wireless devices into a wireless network.

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to use the electrical lines in your house as an Ethernet network.
This is quite secure, as the power-line network will not (normally) be accessible beyond
your apartment/house.

See for example some
[powerline adapters](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_3_9?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=powerline+ethernet+adapter&sprefix=powerline%2Caps%2C312&crid=D1R7ZRAC5VJ8)
on Amazon, and read more in the article
[Powerline networking: what you need to know](https://www.techradar.com/news/networking/powerline-networking-what-you-need-to-know-930691).

Comment: I'm not really a fan of powerline adapters. I've seen too many times that the connection is dropped for unknown reasons and you need to reset the adapters, even on pricey ones. But its a good alternate solution nevertheless.